# How to hide div clicking anywhere on page?

Tags: angularjs

Ok i have main header controller where i have this:

```
<div class="fade-show-hide" ng-class="{'ng-hide':loggedInClose==true}" ng-show="loggedInOpened" ng-cloak>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInPartial.cshtml")
</div>
```

In script i have this:

$scope.loggedInClose = false;

```
  $scope.toggleLoggedIn = function () {
        $scope.loggedInOpened = !$scope.loggedInOpened;
        $scope.languagesOpened = false;
        $scope.loginOpened = false;  
    };
```

Problem is when i use this code nothing happend...i get `$scope.loggedInClose = true;` but div is not hide ...

```
angular.element(document).on('click', function () {

    $scope.loggedInClose = true;

});
```

Can someone explain me how to hide div if i click anywhere on page that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-hide` separately instead of using it inside `ng-class`. So change the HTML to:

```
<div class="fade-show-hide" ng-hide="loggedInClose" ng-show="loggedInOpened" ng-cloak>
```

I think your changes are not getting applied:

use `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.loggedInClose = true;`

See the plunkr "http://plnkr.co/edit/0u7u4InJsJpI4g4E8vvg?p=preview"

Comment: i tried with ng-hide but same problem...its not want to close

Answer (score 1):

I hope you put this event listener in directive, not in controller? :) Anyway, you need to tel Angular to update scope bindings. For this call $apply method to kick off new digest:

```
angular.element(document).on('click', function () {
    $scope.loggedInClose = true;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: i put it in controller...is that a problem?

Comment: Well you should not do DOM stuff in controller. Controller is only a bridge between data and view. All DOM related manipulations should be in the presentation layer. Of course, if you care about good structure and maintainable code. Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). In your case I would say that you need ngClick on body tag, not manual even listener.

Comment: problem is that i dont have body tag because this is partial view...and page have more then one controller ... i have controller for header controller for sidebar and content...